# Type 'Observable<User | null | undefined>

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem that cannot be solved, I have read several similar ones, but I do not understand that it fails, in each case it seems different from mine.

I am trying to get the id to get my blog data from firebase.

This is my problem:

> Error: src / app / components / blogs / blog.service.ts: 26: 5 - Error TS2322: Type 'Observable <BlogsInterface | undefined> 'is not assignable to type' Observable  '.
> Type 'BlogsInterface | undefined 'is not assignable to type' BlogsInterface '.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BlogsInterface'.
> 26 return BlogId;

This is my code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { BlogsInterface } from '../../models/blogs.interface';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BlogService {
  constructor(private angularFS: AngularFirestore) { }
  
  public getBlogs():Observable<BlogsInterface[]>{
    
    return this.angularFS
        .collection('blogs')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
                const data = a.payload.doc.data() as BlogsInterface;
                const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                return {id, ... data};
            }))
        )
  }

  public getBlogId(id: BlogsInterface):Observable<BlogsInterface>{
    const BlogId = this.angularFS.doc<BlogsInterface>(`blogs/${id}`).valueChanges();
    return BlogId;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help, and forgive me if I have not explained myself well or have made a mistake, it is my first time.

Comment: Perhaps `angularFS.doc` might return `undefined` so you should add that to your return type `getBlogId(id: BlogsInterface):Observable<BlogsInterface | undefined>`

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Visual Studio Code you can right click `.valueChanges` > Go to Definition and view the typing of this:

```
export declare class AngularFirestoreDocument<T = DocumentData> {
    ...

    /**
     * Listen to unwrapped snapshot updates from the document.
     *
     * If the `idField` option is provided, document IDs are included and mapped to the
     * provided `idField` property name.
     */
    valueChanges(options?: {}): Observable<T | undefined>;

    ...
}
```

Either you need to type

```
public getBlogId(id: BlogsInterface):Observable<BlogsInterface | undefined>
```

or map `undefined` to an object matching `BlogsInterface` type (if this makes sense for your application)

```
.valueChanges().pipe(
    map(x => {
        if (x === 'undefined') {
            // give a value
        }
        return x
    }))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for responding so quickly.

`public getBlogId (id: BlogsInterface): Observable <BlogsInterface | undefined>`

With this solution the error disappears, but I get the value undefined, so it doesn't work for me, since I need the ID to open the content of each post.

The other solutions I don't understand.

Comment: @DanielGarcía you'll have to handle the `undefined` case e.g. check prior to using and reroute say in a guard or display a UI message.